# Is GoDaddy a good hosting service?

Tags: web-hosting

I was looking for a basic hosting, not big one, with a least 1GB of storage. I took a look at GoDaddy, and it has great prices and really give a lot for that amount.

So that's why I'm wondering, since they have really cheap plans, do you recommend it? If not, can you give me an advice where to get one?

I was interested in their Economy 4GH plan.

I just need, MySQL , PHP, and at least 1GB storage, and 2 DB at least

Comment: We don't generally enter the hosting debate here and have a generic answer '[How to find hosting that meets my requirements](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)' that we refer these types of questions to. Personally I use godaddy for domain management and they're pretty good at it but you definitely get what you pay for in terms of hosting (especially on the support front) it's trial and error really. IMHO Servage do a good job but the support is crap, media temple and gradwell have great support but you pay for it.